# Disabling polygon Label on vertices in Edit Mode using OpenLayers

Tags: openlayers-2, polygon, labeling

I added the style on the polygon layer like so.

```js
var style = $.extend(true, {}, OpenLayers.Feature.Vector.style['default']); // get a copy of the default style
style.label = "1233456 ha"
style.fillOpacity = 0.1
style.strokeWidth = 3
var styleMap = new OpenLayers.StyleMap({"default": style});
polygonLayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("Polygon Layer", {styleMap: styleMap});
```

The polygon looks fine on normal mode.

[image: label on normal mode]

However, on **ModifyFeature**, labels are showing up on every vertex.

[image]

So, I test this http://trac.osgeo.org/openlayers/ticket/2176.

```js
var styleMap = new OpenLayers.StyleMap(new OpenLayers.Style({
        label: "${getLabel}"
        // your other symbolizer properties here
    }, {context: {
        getLabel: function(feature) {
            if(mycontrolIsNotInEditMode) {
                return feature.attributes.label;
            }
        }
    }}
));
```

Then the labels on the vertices are disabled, BUT the label between vertices are still showing up.

How can I disable the labels between the vertices?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can make sure that the geometry is of type polygon so that it only gets the label if it's a polygon and not the line or point. By adding `&& feature.geometry.CLASS_NAME == "OpenLayers.Geometry.Polygon"` to your if statement. That should work.

Like this:

```js
...
getLabel: function (feature) {
    if (mycontrolIsNotInEditMode && feature.geometry.CLASS_NAME == "OpenLayers.Geometry.Polygon") {
        return feature.attributes.label;
    }
}
...
```

Here is a [**Working Example**](http://users8.jabry.com/captdragon/ol/modifyFeature.htm)

This is the important part:

```js
var style = $.extend(true, {}, OpenLayers.Feature.Vector.style['default']); // get a copy of the default style
style.label = "${getLabel}";
style.fillOpacity = 0.1
style.strokeWidth = 3

var styleMap = new OpenLayers.StyleMap({
    "default": new OpenLayers.Style(style, {
        context: {
            getLabel: function (feature) {
                if (feature.geometry && feature.geometry.CLASS_NAME == "OpenLayers.Geometry.Polygon") {
                    return "1233456 ha";
                } else {
                    return "";
                }
            }
        }
    })
});
```

So that it only returns a label if it's a polygon:
[image]

Answer (score 3):

I've faced with the same issue today. Because my layer contains not only polygonal features, solution proposed by CaptDragon didn't work in my case. I've spent couple of hours for resolving my problem and would like to share results.

```javascript
#Create custom symbolizer for virtual vertices (withot label option)
OpenLayers.Feature.Vector.style['virtual'] = {
    fillColor: "#ee9900",
    fillOpacity: 0.4,
    strokeColor: "#ee9900",
    strokeOpacity: 1,
    strokeWidth: 1,
    pointRadius: 3
}

var styleMap = new OpenLayers.StyleMap({
   "default":OpenLayers.Feature.Vector.style['default'],
   "virtual": OpenLayers.Feature.Vector.style['virtual']
}, {extendDefault: false});

var vectors = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector('features', {styleMap: styleMap});
var modify = new OpenLayers.Control.ModifyFeature(vectors, {vertexRenderIntent: "virtual"});
```